# About replacing string with sed

Tags: sed

I'd like to replace all the \r\n with < br/ >in a document, and I'm trying this see script below

```
# sed -i 's/\r\n/<br/>' ~/xxd/*
```

however i got this error back

> sed: -e expression #1, char 12: unknown option to `s'

How do i solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sed - unknown option to  \`s'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366816/sed-unknown-option-to-s)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you have the `/` separator in your replacement string so `sed` is assuming that's the end of your replacement, and that the `>` following it is a flag.

If your `sed` is modern enough, just use a different separator character, one that's *not* in the replacement string:

```
pax$ echo hello | sed -e 's/e/<br />/'
sed: -e expression #1, char 9: unknown option to `s'

pax$ echo hello | sed -e 's?e?<br />?'
h<br />llo
```

Alternatively, you can escape the offending character but I try to avoid that since it tends to lead to overly sawtooth `sed` commands like `/\/\/\/\/\/\`.

The other thing you may want to watch out for is trying to use `\n` in your regex since `sed` operates on lines anyway. If your intent is to just strip carriage returns and insert HTML line breaks, then the following `sed` command may be better:

```
s?\r$?<br />?
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However the output seems wrong

# echo test\r\ntest | sed -e 's?\r$?<br />?'
testrntest

Comment: @xxd: that's because the _shell_ is interpreting those escapes, as can be seen if you just use `echo test\r\ntest` on its own. If you don't want the shell munging them, you need to single-quote the argument.  You'll also probably need `echo -e` to interpret the escapes rather than pass them through as the characters `backslash`, `r`, `backslash`, `n`.

Comment: Not sure what I'm doing wrong but I can't seem to make it work from my end. Tried testing it in cygwin and RHEL5 but cant' make it work. However, I found an alternative: `sed 's|$|<br />|g' file.html`. I figured that I would just replace the end character with `<br />` and indeed it worked!