# Replace the first line in a text file by a string

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I am a newbie at shell scripting, and am confused about how to use `sed` or any other tools to replace the first line in my text file by a string. Here are the text file contents:

```
/home/snehil/Desktop/j1/movie.MOV
"spome other text lines'
```

I want to replace the first line (movie file path) with just `movie.MOV` (could be a variable in the shell script)

Please guide me how to do this. I came across `sed` in some posts, do I need to use `sed` here?

Answer (score 184, accepted):

sed is the right tool, try doing :

```
var="movie.MOV"
sed -i "1s/.*/$var/" file.txt
```

**explanations**

- `1` mean first line
- the rest is the substitution `s///` : we substitute everything (.*) by the `$var` variable
- the double shell quotation is mandatory here

Learn how to quote properly in shell, it's very important :

> "Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and *every* expansion: `"$var"`, `"$(command "$var")"`, `"${array[@]}"`, `"a & b"`. Use `'single quotes'` for code or literal `$'s: 'Costs $5 US'`, `ssh host 'echo "$HOSTNAME"'`. See
> http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes
> http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments
> http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words

Comment: You could also use `1s:.*/::` to strip everything but the file name, if that's what the asker actually wants.

Comment: Hello Sputnick, I am trying your solution: but i get the folwing error char 9: unknown option to `s'          ............. this is my code..........  #!/bin/sh
topDirectoryPath="$1"
metaFileName="movie_meta.txt"  
replaceName="$2"
myMetaFilePath="$topDirectoryPath$metaFileName"
sed "1s/.*//$replaceName/" /home/snehil/Desktop/j1/Erasure/Coding/movie_meta.txt

Comment: I want to replace the first line in myMetaFilePath file to ${2} (which is movie.mOV) ...can u give advice on what could be wrong here? thanks

Comment: As I said, there was a typo, copy & paste one more time

Comment: Thanks! I got the new contents of the file 'echoed' in the terminal... but how do I write this into the same file? i.e write the new contents in the same file? I tried saving the sed in a variable and using > operator.. doesnt wrk :(

Comment: @Rookie you can make `sed` edit the file in place with the `-i` option e.g.
`sed -i '.bak' "1s/.*/${var}/" file.txt` 
`sed` will edit it in-place and create a backup file ( `.bak` ). If you don't need a backup file simply give `sed` a blank parameter for the `-i` option as in:
`sed -i '' "1s/.*/${var}/" file.txt`

Comment: It would be great if the answer is updated with the `-i` option as @SamFigueroa suggests in its comment. The OP is asking for this as it is stated in its last comment of this answer.

Comment: what should I do if my new line contains "/"?

Comment: You can pick one of most of ASCII characters as a delimiter

Comment: Add empty quotes `-i ''` to make the command work on both Linux and Mac.  Mac requires the argument for `-i` while in GNU sed it's optional.

Comment: For anyone trying to replace a shebang line and getting `unknown option to \`s'` from sed... it's because of slash in the replacement text, use a different regex delimiter https://stackoverflow.com/a/9366940/202168

Answer (score 6):

You can do this easy with tail:

```
#I want to replace the first line
cp test.txt test.txt.backup
echo 'mynewfirstline'> test.txt
#add everything from old file starting from second line
cat test.txt.backup |tail -n+2>> test.txt
```

Comment: This feels slow for large files, is this faster or slower than using sed?

Comment: sed is not portable, so this is for not-so-large files clearly better