# How to display the average of multiple runs on tensorboard

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

Is there a way to display the average of multiple different runs on tensorflow?
 I can only see them on the same graph (by sending the path of the different runs), but I want to see their average on the graph

Answer (score 5):

As @dga mentioned this is not implemented yet. Here is some code that uses [`EventAccumulator`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/blob/master/tensorboard/backend/event_processing/event_accumulator.py) to combine scalar tensorflow summary values. This can be extended to accommodate the other summary types.

```
import os
from collections import defaultdict

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorboard.backend.event_processing.event_accumulator import EventAccumulator


def tabulate_events(dpath):

    summary_iterators = [EventAccumulator(os.path.join(dpath, dname)).Reload() for dname in os.listdir(dpath)]

    tags = summary_iterators[0].Tags()['scalars']

    for it in summary_iterators:
        assert it.Tags()['scalars'] == tags

    out = defaultdict(list)

    for tag in tags:
        for events in zip(*[acc.Scalars(tag) for acc in summary_iterators]):
            assert len(set(e.step for e in events)) == 1

            out[tag].append([e.value for e in events])

    return out


def write_combined_events(dpath, d_combined, dname='combined'):

    fpath = os.path.join(dpath, dname)
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(fpath)

    tags, values = zip(*d_combined.items())

    timestep_mean = np.array(values).mean(axis=-1)

    for tag, means in zip(tags, timestep_mean):
        for i, mean in enumerate(means):
            summary = tf.Summary(value=[tf.Summary.Value(tag=tag, simple_value=mean)])
            writer.add_summary(summary, global_step=i)

        writer.flush()

dpath = '/path/to/root/directory'

d = tabulate_events(dpath)

write_combined_events(dpath, d)
```

This solution assumes a directory structure like the following:

```
dpath
├── 1
│   └── events.out.tfevents.1518552132.Alexs-MacBook-Pro-2.local
├── 11
│   └── events.out.tfevents.1518552180.Alexs-MacBook-Pro-2.local
├── 21
│   └── events.out.tfevents.1518552224.Alexs-MacBook-Pro-2.local
├── 31
│   └── events.out.tfevents.1518552264.Alexs-MacBook-Pro-2.local
└── 41
    └── events.out.tfevents.1518552304.Alexs-MacBook-Pro-2.local
```

Comment: There is one problem with this implementation. If there are many iterations than tensorflow seems to cut of some steps so setting "i" here for the global_step is not correct and will lead to unequal curves. global_step needs to be set with the correct step number for every value.

Answer (score 4):

Please follow [issue 376](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/376) to see progress on this.  It's an active feature request with some progress in the last month, but as of now, there's not a way to do what you want.  Yet.

Answer (score 2):

Since there is still no build in functionality to do this I released a tool for that:

https://github.com/Spenhouet/tensorboard-aggregator

This tool can aggregate multiple tensorboard runs by their max, min, mean, median and standard deviation. The aggregates are either saved in new tensorboard summaries or as `.csv` files.

Answer (score 2):

I created [**TensorBoard Reducer**](https://github.com/janosh/tensorboard-reducer) to do this with PyTorch.

```bash
pip install tensorboard-reducer
tb-reducer runs/of-your-model* -o output-dir -r mean,std,min,max
```

The aggregation results can be saved to disk either as new TensorBoard logs or CSV / JSON / Excel files.