# Load epochs logs Keras model

Tags: python, keras

I load the Keras model I have been training with 150 epochs

```
tbCallBack = tensorflow.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir='./Graph', histogram_freq=0, write_graph=True, write_images=True)


my_model.fit(X_train, X_train,
                     epochs=200, 
                     batch_size=100,
                     shuffle=True,
                     validation_data = (X_test, X_test),
                     callbacks=[tbCallBack]
               )

# Save the model
my_model.save('my_model.hdf5')
```

Then, I will load the Keras model

```
my_model = load_model("my_model.hdf5")
```

Is there a way to load all the epochs logs (loss, accuracy.. ) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the keras callback called `CSVLogger`.

According to the [documentation](https://keras.io/callbacks/#csvlogger), it streams the results from each epoch into a csv file.

This is the code from the documentation of it.

```py
from keras.callbacks import CSVLogger

csv_logger = CSVLogger('training.log')
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, callbacks=[csv_logger])
```

You can then manipulate it as a normal CSV file, for your needs.

Comment: Thank you. I guess there is no way to restore the logs from the model I've already trained, right?

Comment: If you used tensorboard for that model, maybe this answer will work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42358524/6590393 . It has the option of losses per epoch too.