# Renaming csv headers in pandas without writing the whole file over for a very large csv

Tags: pandas, google-bigquery

Im trying to import the csv to google big query , but in the schema it does not allow header names with space. And my csv has several headers with spaces in between. The problem is, the csv file is 50gb. So I cannot open it in memory , rename and write it. Would be much obliged if I could know if there is a more convenient way to accomplish this in pandas.

Comment: and, [How can I strip the whitespace from Pandas DataFrame headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21606987/how-can-i-strip-the-whitespace-from-pandas-dataframe-headers)

Comment: The question marked as duplicate loads the whole file in memory. My problem is the file is of 50GB so cannot go for that approach.

Comment: Why not use bash for header cleaning?

Comment: Thanks, was able to do it with sed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13438095/replace-1st-line-in-a-text-file-by-a-string-shell-scripting

Comment: This is a great example of what people mean when they say that questions are closed prematurely on Stack Overflow.