# Ignoring slashes in sed find and replace command

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to do a find and replace using sed in a terminal.

Within the apache config file, I'm trying to replace:

`DocumentRoot /var/www`

with

`DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite.com/public_html`

From the command line, without using an editor.  I'd like to do this with sed, and I've tried various iterations of:

`sudo sed -i 's/'DocumentRoot /var/www'/'DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite.com/public_html'/' /etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite.com`

However when doing so I get this error:
`sed: -e expression #1, char 14: unterminated s command`

So it's erroring on the slashes in the paths.  How do I get around this?

Thanks for your help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sed - unknown option to  \`s'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366816/sed-unknown-option-to-s)

Comment: Note that in your apache configuration file, there is often a directive like: <Directory "/var/www">... some options ... </Directory> and you need to change the path there as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It isn't necessary to use `/` as the regex delimiter. You can use `#` or `@` when your regular expressions contain `/` that you would otherwise need to escape.

```
sed -i s#expr1#expr2#
```

So, it could be:

```
sudo sed -i 's#DocumentRoot /var/www#DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite.com/public_html#' /etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite.com
```

Also, as your substitution-argument itself contains spaces, you need to enclose them in single-quotes.

Comment: minor edit to yours worked: `sudo sed -i 's#DocumentRoot /var/www#DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite.com/public_html#' /etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite.com`

Comment: @gcubed Looks like I placed the delims in the wrong places, for your requirement. Glad it worked :)

Answer (score 4):

It is not compulsory to use `/` as separator in `sed`. `sed 's/hi/hey/` is same as `sed 's#hi#hey#'`