# Double quotes and variables in Sed - Unknown expression?

Tags: bash, variables, sed

Right, so in a Bash script I have the following line:

```
sed -i 's/$/,"123456","789101112","0001",'"$THEDATE"',"DDX"/' /tmp/tmp02.csv
```

However, whenever I run it I always get the error

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 42: unknown option to `s'
```

I think it's the variable bit, but however I do it it won't seem to escape the double quotes.. Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sed - unknown option to  \`s'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366816/sed-unknown-option-to-s)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have slashes in `THEDATE`, which are being confused as regex delimiters by sed. Try changing the substitution delimiter, for example with `!`:

```
sed -i 's!$!,"123456","789101112","0001",'"$THEDATE"',"DDX"!' /tmp/tmp02.csv
```

Comment: And just like that it's worked! You are quite right with the slashes in the date, I didn't even consider that! Thank you very much :)