# Sed replace error

Tags: sed

I have a pattern I am trying to match:

```
<x>anything</x>
```

I am trying to replace 'anything' (which can be any text, not the text anything - (.*)) with 'something' so any occurrences would become:

```
<x>something</x>
```

I am trying to use the following sed command:

```
sed "s/<x>.*</x>/<x>something</x>/g" file
```

I am getting the following error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 19: unknown option to `s'
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sed - unknown option to  \`s'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366816/sed-unknown-option-to-s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slashes in the closing XML tags are confusing it. Try escaping them like this:

```
sed "s/<x>.*<\/x>/<x>something<\/x>/g" file
```

You can apparently also use [an equals sign](http://alldunne.org/2011/01/escaping-the-forward-slash-character-with-sed/) which I'd never seen before. I'll be changing a bunch of scripts when I get to work!

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/(<x>)[^<]*/\1something/g' file
```

This looks to replace `<x>` and something which is not a `<` by `<x>something` repeatedly on the same line.

N.B. `.*` is greedy and may well swallow up further tags on the same line.