# Unknown option to 's' in a sed script

Tags: shell, unix, sed, scripting

I am trying to make a simple replacement for an IPv4 address script.

Here is my code.

```
#!/bin/sh

sed 's/[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}/192.100.100.100/g/'
```

What is happening is every time I call:

```
example.sed example1 > example.output
```

I get:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 75: unknown option to `s'
```

where the 75th char is the 1 from 192.100.100.100.

Why?

Comment: This is not a duplicate, but in case you were googling the error message, the usual cause is in this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366816/sed-unknown-option-to-s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drop the trailing slash!

```
sed -e \
   's/[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}/192.100.100.100/g'
```

(The split over two lines attempts to ensure visibility of the end of the string.)

Note that `sed` starts counting at the `s` at the start of the `s///` string, not at the start of the `sed` word.  The trailing `/` was at character 75 in that string.

The full script should probably add "all the command line arguments" (aka `"$@"`) too:

```
sed -e \
   's/[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}/192.100.100.100/g' \
   "$@"
```

This will read files if they're specified (and would also accept extra editing commands such as `-e 's/.*//'`!) or standard input if no arguments are specified.  You can put it all on one line in your script; the breaks are for improved clarity on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Well, that is embarrassing. Thank you for your help. I tried that and my shell just freezes after I enter my file command. Any ideas?

Comment: It's waiting for you to type the data?  Try control-D; it should exit the `sed` and not your shell.

Comment: "Note that sed starts counting at the s" That makes sense. Ok,thank you again!