# How to pass a variable containing slashes to sed

Tags: bash, sed

How do you pass a variable containing slashes as a pattern to `sed`?

For example, if I have the following variable:

```
var="/Users/Documents/name/file"
```

I want to pass it to `sed` as so:

```
sed "s/$var/replace/g" "$file"
```

However I get errors. How can I circumvent the issue?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864146/using-different-delimiters-in-sed-commands-and-range-addresses

Answer (score 299, accepted):

Use an alternate regex delimiter as `sed` allows you to use any delimiter (**including control characters**):

```
sed "s~$var~replace~g" $file
```

---

As mentioned above we can use control character as delimiter as well like:

```
sed "s^[$var^[replace^[g" file
```

Where `^[` is typed by pressing <kbd>Ctrl-V-3</kbd> together.

Or else in `bash` shell you can use this `sed` with `\03` as delimiter:

```sh
d=$'\03'
sed "s${d}$var${d}replace$d" file
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I try   sed -i "s~blah~$var~g file"   and get: "sed -e expression #1, char 70: unterminated `s' command". I have confirmed that the culprit is a slash in $var. Variants of this solution to this are all over the place and none of them work. Was sed recently updated? I'm on v4.2.2 on Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS.

Comment: That depends on what is value of `$var`

Comment: Doesn't work with ~ as @PaulEricson observed, but still works with |

Comment: don't work for me. I get ```sed: -e expression #1, char 17: unknown option to `s'``` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/27788661/860878 worked)

Comment: The last "~" (after g) seems not to be needed, at least for AWS Amazon Linux (CentOS based)

Answer (score 97):

A pure bash answer: use [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to backslash-escape any slashes in the variable:

```
var="/Users/Documents/name/file"
sed "s/${var//\//\\/}/replace/g" $file
```

Comment: This is a good way, because you don't always know what characters contains the variable. So you can always escape the sed delimiter if there is a doubt.For instance : sed "s:${var//:/\\:}:replace:g" $file

Comment: Beautiful. Made some renaming scripts of mine much cleaner.

Comment: Learned something beautiful today, thank you. Should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Some clarity on the pattern being used here: `${parameter/pattern/string}`. So, in this case, the parameter is `var`, the pattern is `/\/`, and the string is `\\/`. All instances of the pattern are replaced because the pattern begins with a `/`.

Comment: @josh, and so the leading slash of the pattern is not actually part of the pattern to replace.

Comment: @glennjackman true, though in the documentation you reference they say "If pattern begins with ‘/’, all matches of pattern are replaced with string." I was following their convention as talking about it as part of the pattern. It does seem an awkward way to talk about it though but the syntax is pretty awkward to begin with in my opinion.

Answer (score 43):

Another way of doing it, although uglier than anubhava's answer, is by escaping all the backslashes in `var` using another `sed` command:

```
var=$(echo "$var" | sed 's/\//\\\//g')
```

then, this will work:

```
sed "s/$var/replace/g" $file
```

Answer (score 16):

Using `/` in sed as a delimiter will conflict with the slashes in the variable when substituted and as a result you will get an error. One way to circumvent this is to use another delimiter that is unique from any characters that is  in that variable.

```
var="/Users/Documents/name/file"
```

you can use the octothorpe character which suits the occasion (or any other character that is not a `/` for ease of use)

```
sed "s#$var#replace#g"
```

or

```
sed 's#$'$var'#replace#g'
```

this is suitable when the variable does not contain spaces

or

```
sed 's#$"'$var'"#replace#g'
```

It is wiser to use the above since we are interested in substituting whatever is in that variable only as compared to double quoting the whole command which can cause  your shell to interpet any character that might be considered a special shell character to the shell.

Comment: Doesn't work. I try   sed -i "s~blah~$var~g file"   and get: "sed -e expression #1, char 70: unterminated `s' command". I have confirmed that the culprit is a slash in $var. Variants of this solution to this are all over the place and none of them work. Was sed recently updated? I'm on v4.2.2 on Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS.

Comment: @PaulEricson I am unable to repro this on any Ubuntu available to me. If your `$var` contains `~`, you will obviously need to pick a different delimiter. The "unterminated" error sounds like your `$var` contains a newline; you might be able to fix it by backslash-escaping every newline in the value, but I don't think this is entirely portable. This is by and large unrelated to the problem of slashes in the value.

Comment: @PaulEricson Oh and your quoting is incorrect, you should not have the file name inside quotes. `sed -i "s~blah~$var~g" file` with quotes only around the actual `sed` script.

Answer (score 8):

This is an old question, but none of the answers here discuss operations other than `s/from/to/` in much detail.

The general form of a `sed` statement is

```
*address* *action*
```

where *address* can be a regex range or a line number range (or empty, in which case the *action* is applied to every input line). So for example

```
sed '1,4d' file
```

will delete lines 1 through 4 (the *address* is the line number range `1,4` and the *action* is the `d` delete command); and

```
sed '/ick/,$s/foo/bar/' file
```

will replace the first occurrence of `foo` with `bar` on any line between the first match on the regex `ick` and the end of the file (the *address* is the range `/ick/,$` and the *action* is the `s` substitute command `s/foo/bar/`).

In this context, if `ick` came from a variable, you could do

```
sed "/$variable/,\$s/foo/bar/"
```

(notice the use of double quotes instead of single, so that the shell can interpolate the variable, and the necessity to quote the literal dollar sign inside double quotes) but if the variable contains a slash, you will get a syntax error. (The shell expands the variable, then passes the resulting string to `sed`;  so `sed` only sees literal text - it has no concept of the shell's variables.)

The cure is to use a different delimiter (where obviously you need to be able to use a character which cannot occur in the variable's value), but unlike in the `s%foo%bar%` case, you also need a backslash before the delimiter if you want to use a different delimiter than the default `/`:

```
sed "\\%$variable%,\$s/foo/bar/" file
```

(inside single quotes, a single backslash would obviously suffice); or you can separately escape every slash in the value. This particular syntax is Bash only:

```
sed "/${variable//\//\\/}/,\$s/foo/bar/" file
```

or if you use a different shell, try

```
escaped=$(echo "$variable" | sed 's%/%\\/%g')
sed "s/$escaped/,\$s/foo/bar/" file
```

For clarity, if `$variable` contained the string `1/2` then the above commands would be equivalent to

```
sed '\%1/2%,$s/foo/bar/' file
```

in the first case, and

```
sed '/1\/2/,$s/foo/bar/' file
```

in the second.

Answer (score 6):

Use Perl, where variables are first class citizens, not just expanding macros:

```
var=/Users/Documents/name/file perl -pe 's/\Q$ENV{var}/replace/g' $file
```

- `-p` reads the input line by line and prints the line after processing
- `\Q` quotes all the metacharacters in the following string (not needed for the value presented here, but necessary if the value contained `[` or some other values special for regular expresisons)

Comment: The only generally useful answer to dozens of "using variables in sed expression" questions across Stack Exchange. Everything else is effectively "escape anything which is special to sed", which is practically useless given the variability of variables and of sed.

Answer (score 1):

You can give `sed` command using any character as the delimiter. For example, with character `#` as `sed`'s delimiter, you can replace `cat` with `dog` like so:

```
sed -i s#cat#dog#g test.txt
```

If you are using variables then

```
sed -i s#$var#replace#g $file
```