# SED : cant replace line in file, sed: -e expression #1, char 32: unknown option to `s'

Tags: sed

i am trying to replace a single line in an existing file as

```
sed -i -e 's/# elasticsearch.url: "http://localhost:9200"/elasticsearch.url: "http://myOwnHost:9200"/g' config/kibana.yml
```

but i get an error

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 32: unknown option to `s'
```

i can figure out how and what to escape here. I am quite new to sed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass a variable containing slashes to sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27787536/how-to-pass-a-variable-containing-slashes-to-sed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `sed` statement the `/` character is used a separator. e.g. `s/search/replace/g`. Since you have `/`s in your string it is messing things up. While `/` is usually used as the separator, you can use other characters. In your case I would use a pipe `|` e.g. `s|search|replace|g`. Alternatively you can use `/` and escape the slashes in your strings: `\/`, but that gets messy.

Comment: do i need to escape `#`?

Comment: Nope, unless you decide to use `#` as your separator, which is another common alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the forward slash characters with backslashes!

```
sed -i -e 's/# elasticsearch.url: "http:\/\/localhost:9200"/elasticsearch.url: "http:\/\/myOwnHost:9200"/g' config/kibana.yml
```