# Bash : Replace path in config file using parameter

Tags: linux, bash, elasticsearch

I have elasticsearch.yml file.

I need to update path.data and path.logs value based on user input.

I wrote .sh script to take path as argument and replace string but it replaces with empty value.

Under script am using this

```
sed -i.bak -e 's/# path.data:.*/  path.data: $2 /' "$1"
sed -i.bak -e 's/# path.logs:.*/  path.logs: $3 /' "$1"
```

**Example** : `./updateconfig.sh /usr/local/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml /var/lib/elasticsearch /var/log/elasticsearch`

I tried with double quotes (") too but no luck.

Can you please help me on this.

**Update**

Adding example and error when trying with different options

**Example** :

```
sed -i.bak -e "s/# path.data:.*/  path.data: $2 /" "$1"
sed -i.bak -e 's># path.data:.*>  path.data: $2 >' "$1"
sed -i.bak -e "'s># path.data:.*>  path.data: $2 >'" "$1"
```

**Errors**:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 32: unknown option to `s'
>   sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command:`''

Comment: You need to use double quotes, please show the example of your attempt at using them.

Comment: if i use double quotes, I get an error
sed: -e expression #1, char 32: unknown option to `s'

example : sed -i.bak -e "s/# path.data:.*/  path.data: $2 /" "$1"

Comment: Use a different delimiter

Comment: Tried with different delimeter but no luck. Again error
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `''

Comment: Please show an example of you using a different delimiter

Comment: This pretty much collects all the common `sed` errors in one question, so singling out a single duplicate is precarious.  Quoting is explained in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306007/replace-a-string-in-shell-script-using-a-variable and using the wrong delimiter is in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27787536/how-to-pass-a-variable-containing-slashes-to-sed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was mangling somewhat with `sed` from the examples over [here](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_tool_guides/the_sed_faq/sedfaq4_023.html), and I was able to make these commands work, if the variables names are known in prior:-

After receiving the arguments in prior: `$1`,`$2` and `$3`

```
sed -i -e "s|^path.data.*|path.data:$2$1|g" -e "s|^path.logs.*|path.logs:$3$1|g" file
```

Assuming my sample file is dummy like below but having actual variable names:-

```
path.data:/l/m/n
path.logs:/d/e/f
```

With the script, below am able to do in-place substitution of paths as needed in OP:-

```
#!/bin/bash

sed -i -e "s|^path.data.*|path.data:$2$1|g" -e "s|^path.logs.*|path.logs:$3$1|g" file
```

On running the script:-

```
$ ./script.sh /usr/local/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml /var/lib/elasticsearch /var/log/elasticsearch
```

On verifying the contents of the original file now:-

```
path.data:/var/lib/elasticsearch/usr/local/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
path.logs:/var/log/elasticsearch/usr/local/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
```

Thanks to [`tripleee`'s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee) suggestion, I am able to do in-place substitution now!

Comment: Just pass multiple `-e` options.  See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657647/combining-2-sed-commands