# passing sed argument with slash ( making a directory a string ?)

Tags: bash, sed, replace, slash

I am trying to pass in assets/css/images to replace images in multiple files.

### So I wrote this script

```
$list
$word
$neword
$i

echo "select files: "
read list
echo "input word to search for: "
read word
echo "input word to replace with: "
read neword

for i in $list
do
sed -i "s/${word}/${neword}/g" $i
```

### done

It works for words without a /, and I can see why, but I don't know how to get around it. Anyone?

Comment: i  mean to replace the string "images" with the string "assets/css/images"

Comment: the error I am getting is:  sed -e expression #1, char 17: unknown option to 's'

Comment: Would this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27787536/how-to-pass-a-variable-containing-slashes-to-sed?

Comment: Is the list of variable interpolations at the beginning of the script really part of your code?  It would do nothing useful if the variables are unset, and potentially something bad if not.

Comment: grundic, thank you for pointing that out. I couldn't find that for the life of me. Thank you!

Comment: triplee, Sorry as I am new to bash scripting. So the list at the top was not neccessary. I deleted it and it worked the same. Good to know! thank you! Out of curiosity, what do you mean b something bad could happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do like this to escape `/` in `sed`

Try Following,

```
sed -i "s#${word}#${neword}#g" "$i"
```

or

```
sed -i "s~${word}~${neword}~g" "$i"
```

Edit: Added Quotes to Filename as Suggested by @tripleee for avoiding condition like filename contains in `$i` have spaces.

Comment: You should also add double quotes around `"$i"`.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much! I am new to bash. That helped a great deal thank you so much. I used the one with the ~ and it worked!

Comment: Still it works for you. But please google your question before asking another question. Cheers. :)