# sed: -e expression #1, char 66: unknown option to s'

Tags: sed

My variables *issuer* and *subject* contains

> issuer=C=IN,ST=TN,L=XYZ,O=ABC,OU=CA,CN=XYZ.com/emailAddress=xyz@gmail
>   subject=C=GB,ST=London,L=London,O=Global_Security,OU=IT,CN=example.comCA/emailAddress=acl@123

I want to replace a variable `leftid` and `leftca` with *subject* and *issuer* in **xyz.conf** respectively.

I'm using sed command like this

```
sed -i -e '/leftid=/s/=.*/= '$subject'/' /etc/xyz.conf
```

and

```
sed -i -e '/leftca=/s/=.*/= '$issuer'/' /etc/xyz.conf
```

But I'm getting the following error(s)

> sed: -e expression #1, char 66: unknown option to `s' sed: -e
>   expression #1, char 83: unknown option to`s'

Can anyone help?

Comment: pick a delimiter that is not part of the string for sed s command. There are / in both strings.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass a variable containing slashes to sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27787536/how-to-pass-a-variable-containing-slashes-to-sed)

Answer (score 0):

Your `$issuer` variable is expanded in the sed substitution part and so the expression becomes:

```
sed -i -e '/leftca=/s/=.*/= 'C=IN,ST=TN,L=XYZ,O=ABC,OU=CA,CN=XYZ.com/emailAddress=xyz@gmail'/' /etc/xyz.conf
```

and this is not a correct sed expression since there is 4 occurrences of the `/` delimiter.

To sum up your sed command is right just change the s substitution command separator with something not present in your issuer variable, like for instance:

```
sed -i -e '/leftid=/ s|=.*|= '$subject'|' /etc/xyz.conf
```