# Can't Build Container Optimized OS | sed: -e expression #2, char 60: unknown option to `s'

Tags: google-cloud-platform, sed, google-container-os

When following [their documentation](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/how-to/building-from-open-source) and running `./build_packages --board=lakitu`, I get the following error.

Using ubuntu 16.0.4. Looks like a sed syntax error? Am I missing a variable? Does sed work differently in different operating systems or is something wrong with their documentation/scripts? Followed their documentation to the t and didn't add or configure anything. Waiting for a successful run first.

[Looking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22182050/sed-e-expression-1-char-23-unknown-option-to-s) [at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36317963/sed-e-expression-1-char-21-unknown-option-to-s) [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47157112/sed-e-expression-1-char-66-unknown-option-to-s) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41621059/sed-e-expression-1-char-54-unknown-option-to-s), they all appear to be syntax errors...

```
 * Package:    sys-boot/shim-14.0.20180308-r4
 * Repository: lakitu
 * USE:        abi_x86_64 amd64 elibc_glibc kernel_linux userland_GNU
 * FEATURES:   network-sandbox sandbox splitdebug userpriv usersandbox
 * Running stacked hooks for pre_pkg_setup
 *    sysroot_build_bin_dir ...                                          [ ok ]
 * Running stacked hooks for post_pkg_setup
 *    python_eclass_hack ...                                             [ ok ]
 * Running stacked hooks for pre_src_unpack
 *    python_multilib_setup ...                                          [ ok ]
>>> Unpacking source...
>>> Unpacking shim-14.0.20180308.tar.gz to /build/lakitu/tmp/portage/sys-boot/shim-14.0.20180308-r4/work
>>> Source unpacked in /build/lakitu/tmp/portage/sys-boot/shim-14.0.20180308-r4/work
 * Running stacked hooks for post_src_unpack
 *    asan_init ...                                                      [ ok ]
>>> Preparing source in /build/lakitu/tmp/portage/sys-boot/shim-14.0.20180308-r4/work/shim-79cdb2a215de2ace7d1bf0a294165a04b726c70a ...
>>> Source prepared.
>>> Configuring source in /build/lakitu/tmp/portage/sys-boot/shim-14.0.20180308-r4/work/shim-79cdb2a215de2ace7d1bf0a294165a04b726c70a ...
>>> Source configured.
>>> Compiling source in /build/lakitu/tmp/portage/sys-boot/shim-14.0.20180308-r4/work/shim-79cdb2a215de2ace7d1bf0a294165a04b726c70a ...
make -j8 ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE=x86_64-cros-linux-gnu- EFI_INCLUDE=/build/lakitu//usr/include/efi EFI_PATH=/build/lakitu//usr/lib64 ARCH_LDFLAGS=--no-experimental-use-relr COMMITID=79cdb2a215de2ace7d1bf0a294165a04b726c70a DEFAULT_LOADER=\\\\grub-lakitu.efi shimx64.efi
sed     -e "s,@@VERSION@@,14," \
        -e "s,@@UNAME@@,Linux x86_64 Intel Xeon E312xx (Sandy Bridge, IBRS update) GenuineIntel GNU/Linux," \
        -e "s,@@COMMIT@@,79cdb2a215de2ace7d1bf0a294165a04b726c70a," \
        < /build/lakitu/tmp/portage/sys-boot/shim-14.0.20180308-r4/work/shim-79cdb2a215de2ace7d1bf0a294165a04b726c70a/version.c.in > version.c
sed: -e expression #2, char 60: unknown option to `s'
make: *** [Makefile:183: version.c] Error 1
 * ERROR: sys-boot/shim-14.0.20180308-r4::lakitu failed (compile phase):
 *   emake failed
 *
 * If you need support, post the output of `emerge --info '=sys-boot/shim-14.0.20180308-r4::lakitu'`,
 * the complete build log and the output of `emerge -pqv '=sys-boot/shim-14.0.20180308-r4::lakitu'`.
 * The complete build log is located at '/build/lakitu/tmp/portage/logs/sys-boot:shim-14.0.20180308-r4:20190531-002217.log'.
 * For convenience, a symlink to the build log is located at '/build/lakitu/tmp/portage/sys-boot/shim-14.0.20180308-r4/temp/build.log'.
 * The ebuild environment file is located at '/build/lakitu/tmp/portage/sys-boot/shim-14.0.20180308-r4/temp/environment'.
 * Working directory: '/build/lakitu/tmp/portage/sys-boot/shim-14.0.20180308-r4/work/shim-79cdb2a215de2ace7d1bf0a294165a04b726c70a'
 * S: '/build/lakitu/tmp/portage/sys-boot/shim-14.0.20180308-r4/work/shim-79cdb2a215de2ace7d1bf0a294165a04b726c70a'
```

Comment: You can easily break out that one `sed` statement and debug this in your shell.

Comment: But can I dig up the script :grimace:

Comment: I see your point, however, if someone here posts a fix you will still need to find that script. I look at the sed statement and I do not see an error. Make sure your system is up to date.

Comment: Honestly, the confirmation is what I was looking for. Working with some image on our OpenStack service. After an update still have that error on ubuntu so just going to switch it up. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 4):

There's a `,` after `Bridge`

```
    -e "s,@@UNAME@@,Linux x86_64 Intel Xeon E312xx (Sandy Bridge, IBRS update) GenuineIntel GNU/Linux," \
```

Change to

```
    -e "s#@@UNAME@@#Linux x86_64 Intel Xeon E312xx (Sandy Bridge, IBRS update) GenuineIntel GNU/Linux#" \
```

Comment: Good eyes. I did not even see that.

Comment: Is there a location? Im running `(cr) centos@centosbuilder ~/trunk/src $ grep -rnw . -e '-e "s,@@UNAME@@,Linux x86_64 Intel Xeon E312xx (Sandy Bridge, IBRS update) GenuineIntel GNU/Linux,"'` right now but its taking forever and the first time I was too flooded with permission denied errors I couldn't scroll up to find the source since I was in a screen. Its not just in the scripts directory so just doing my best here.

Comment: @quantomworks `shim-14.0.20180308-r4`  `./Makefile:  -e "s,@@UNAME@@,$(shell uname -s -m -p -i -o)," `