# sed: -e expression #1, char 30: unknown option to `s'

Tags: sed, cmd

I have this as variable

```
set var=1920 x 1080p / 23.976 fps /16:9 / High Profile 4.1
```

and i will replace with sed

```
sed -e "s/1920/%var%/" movie.txt > movie2.txt.nfo
```

error output is

```
ed: -e expression #1, char 30: unknown option to `s'
```

I do not understand what's wrong

Regards

Comment: Try to change the delimiter, something like: `sed -e "s-1920-%var%-"`

Comment: big thx, working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass a variable containing slashes to sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27787536/how-to-pass-a-variable-containing-slashes-to-sed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with slashes. Your final command will have many slashes coming from the variable itself, which will be confused with the `/` delimiter you provided in the `sed` command itself.

Luckily, `sed` can have any char as the delimiter. Change to something like:

```
 sed -e "s-1920-%var%-"
```

Now, `-` won't be confused with `/` (from the variable).