# replacing a variable literal value in file using sed

Tags: linux, sed

I need to replace a literal variable value in a file, I'm trying to use SED but it doesn't seem to be working.  Below is the command I'm using, but when I check the file the value hasn't changed.

```
sed -i .bak "s|isJBossRunning \\\${home}|isJBossRunning \\\${home_dir}|g" /file/location/file.sh
```

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do. In my file.sh file.

```
home='/opt/tmp'

home_dir='/usr/share/jbossas'

JBOSS_USER=jbossas

SERVER_NAME=abxd

echo isJBossRunning ${JBOSS_USER} ${home} ${SERVER_NAME}
```

So what I want to do is replace the string `isJBossRunning ${JBOSS_USER} ${home} ${SERVER_NAME}` so I replace the `${home}` with `${home_dir}`.

Comment: What value are you trying to replace and by what?

Comment: Please let us know the values of $home, and $home_dir, and the contents of file.sh

Comment: I'm not trying to replace the value of those variables, I just want to replace the text within the file so that "isJBossRunning ${home}" is replaced with "isJBossRunning ${home_dir}.

Comment: [What characters do I need to escape when using sed in a sh script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/32907/56041), [Escape a string for a sed replace pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/407523/608639), [How to pass a variable containing slashes to sed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27787536/608639), [Is there a way to prevent sed from interpreting the replacement string?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/255789/56041), etc.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way of updating the file.  Below is the command I used, I just replaced the literal variable in the entire file.

```
sed -i "s/\${home}/\${home_dir}/" ./file.sh
```