# how to ignore special characters in a file while doing sed

Tags: javascript, sed

I need to replace a string with contents of a json file. So my code goes like

```
value=$(<minified.json)
sed -i -e "s/<!--MyJson-->/$value/" file.html
```

I need to replace the contents of json file to `<!--MyJson-->` string in file.html.

Issue happens because some array elements in json have `/` so because of that it fails with error

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 438: unknown option to `s'
```

But I cant change that text in json. So how can i make my sed command to ignore the backslash in the copy text. Or how can i make it as a blind replace.

Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass a variable containing slashes to sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27787536/how-to-pass-a-variable-containing-slashes-to-sed)

Answer (score 1):

You can use different delimiters in substitution:

```
sed -i -e "s%<!--MyJson-->%$value%" file.html
```

(Provided `%` isn't used in the json).

Or switch to Perl where variables are first class citizens, not just expanding macros as in the shell:

```
value=$value perl -i~ -pe 's/<!--MyJson-->/$ENV{value}/' -- file.html
```

- `-p` reads the input line by line and prints it after processing
- the ENV hash contains environmental variables, setting the variable on the same line exports it to the following command