# Replacing full line with sed

Tags: perl, sed

Im trying to use sed command in order to find an error in my text file and replace it with something else.

like i said before sed works perfectly for me without using double quotes in the text, also this -> ~ doesnt work like you suggested, unless i used it wrong.
The Perl script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
my @array = (
"^OPTIONS.*\-X",
"^OPTIONS.*\-x"
);

my $Replace_To = 'OPTIONS="-u hello:bye -p /var/run/myfile.pid -g"'
chomp $Replace_To;
my strCommand;
my $array;

sub main
{
   my $hostname = `hostname -s`;
   chomp $hostname;
   foreach $array(@array)
   {
       my $execute = `awk '/$array/' /tmp/file.txt
       if($execute)
       {
          chomp $execute;
          $strCommand = `sed -i 's/$execute/$Replace_To/g' /tmp/file.txt`;
       }
   }

}
&main();
```

Comment: You implemented sed in perl? Like the old [psed](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::s2p)? Nice.

Comment: (Assuming OP is _calling_ `sed` _from_ Perl.) There’s no reason to use `sed` in Perl. Perl can do all `sed` can.

Comment: As for the error it looks like (it would be nice to see the actual code, BTW) you’re trying to use a variable within the `sed` command but the variable contains slashes, in which case see [How to pass a variable containing slashes to sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27787536/how-to-pass-a-variable-containing-slashes-to-sed). Or just use plain Perl.

Comment: @Tal Your question is unclear. Are you _implementing_ `sed` in Perl or are you _using_ it? Please show some code, preferably a [mcve]. And the title doesn’t quite match the rest of the question.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, forget about perl for a sec, i'm trying to run that command from shell itself:
sed -i 's/myname="jorge: and im 27 years old -X /tmp/wow/bla -g/myname="Dan: and im 27 years old /tmp/wow/bla -g/g' /tmp/test.txt

Comment: @Tal You’re using slashes as delimiters for the `s` command but you’ve got too many slashes. Once agian, see [How to pass a variable containing slashes to sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27787536/how-to-pass-a-variable-containing-slashes-to-sed).

Comment: @Tal Or just write it all in Perl. It’ll be much easier.

Comment: @Biffen I've posted the example code

Comment: @Tal There’s _never_ a need to call `sed` (or `awk`) from Perl. Perl’s text parsing and regex engine are two of its best features. As for putting a variable in a regex; [`quotemeta`](https://perldoc.pl/functions/quotemeta) is your friend.

Comment: @Biffen i'm in close env and not all modules / features are available for me.
but its ok, i found the solution.
thanks anyway :)

Comment: @Tal `sed`-like line iteration and regexen are at the very core of the Perl language, no extra features or modules required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution i found for my problem is pretty simple:
just had to put \ before every / i had in my text.