# How to insert a variable content using sed command

Tags: shell, sed

I have shell script (.sh) and I'm trying to insert contents of a file onto another file using the following commands but I it's throwing an error "sed: -e expression #1, char 28: unknown option to `s'":

```
filename="/home/user1/filename.txt"
contents=$(du -sh /var/log/test.log)
hostname > $filename
sed -i "/test_string/ s/$/, $contents" $filename
```

I can't seem to figure out where the underlying issue is. Can someone please help?

Example:

filename=`/home/user1/filename.txt`

hostname = `server1.mydomain.com`

So the content of `$filename` is `server1.mydomain.com` after running `hostname > $filename`.

The output of `du -sh /var/log/test.log` command is let say `1.3M    /var/log/test.log`

So running `sed -i "/mydomain.com/ s/$/, $contents" $filename` should update the content of the following filename to:

`server1.mydomain.com, 1.3M    /var/log/test.log`

But as I mentioned above, it's throwing an error.

Comment: Syntax of `s` command: `s/regex/replace/` with three `/`.

Comment: sed -i "/test_string/s/$/, $contents/" $filename

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/27787536/3266847 as you're inserting a variable containing forward slashes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass a variable containing slashes to sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27787536/how-to-pass-a-variable-containing-slashes-to-sed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
sed -i  "s#\$#, ${contents}#g"
```

Demo :

```
$cat file.txt 
server1.mydomain.com
$echo $contents 
1.3M /var/log/test.log
$sed -i  "s#\$#, ${contents}#g"  file.txt 
$cat file.txt 
server1.mydomain.com, 1.3M    /var/log/test.log
$
```

`sed` command usage is `s#pattern to search#pattern/String replacement#occurence`

Comment: you can use arbitraty delimiters in sed commands, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864146/using-different-delimiters-in-sed-commands-and-range-addresses

Answer (score 0):

This is easier done with `perl` or another language, to avoid the issues with characters in your variable causing `sed` parse errors:

```
contents=$(du -sh /var/log/test.log) perl -pi -e '$_ .= ", $ENV{contents}" if /test_string/' "$filename"
```

Or using `ed` to **ed**it the file, and avoiding the `$contents` variable completely:

```
ed -s "$filename" <<'EOF'
/test_string/a
,<space>
.
r !du -sh /var/log/test.log
.-2,.j
w
EOF
```

Replace `<space>` with a literal space.

This cryptic-at-first set of commands first moves to the first line matching the regular expression `test_string`, then **a**ppends a line `,<space>` after it, then **r**eads the output of the `du` command and inserts it in a line after that, and finally **j**oins those three lines into one and **w**rites the modified file back to disk.

(This assumes that the `du` invocation will only return one line.)

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't have ed or perl installed on our servers. :(

Comment: (Especially at the lack of `ed` since it's a standard POSIX utility)