# Replace string starting with (preferable without sed)

Tags: android, bash, sed

I'm trying to replace all line which starts with say `Replace_ME`. I used,

```
sed  -i -e "s/^Replace_ME.*$/Replace_ME=${Replaced}/" "$filename"
```

Though it works well with Linux but on android it's completely clearing the `$filename` file! for that reason I'm currently using,

```
sed -i "8i\Replace_ME=${Replaced}" "$filename"
sed -i "231i\Replace_ME=${Replaced}" "$filename"
```

which is very inefficient as you can see. Is there any alternative way of replacing line starting with keyword other than sed say awk? But at the same time compatible with android?
Thanks for reading this.

Comment: How do you run sed on android?

Comment: terminal emulator, magisk module

Comment: Can you give us the output on the android device of `file "$filename"` with $filename as one of your files ?

Comment: say `Replaced=done replacing` then the output will be `Replace_ME=done replacing` in `$filename` file

Comment: @Some53 : Could it be that the bash on Android for some reason has an internal variable `$/` defined? This would ruin your command. You could - for a test - run it with `set -x` turned on.

Comment: I actually tried without `$` as well eg. `sed  -i -e "s/^Replace_ME.*/Replace_ME=${Replaced}/" "$filename"` but same result, all contents of `$filename` gets cleared

Comment: I would want to start by finding out what version of `sed` and `awk` is running on android; please update the question with the output from `sed --version` and `awk --version`

Comment: if you remove the `-i` flag, does `sed` generate the desired output?

Comment: when you say 'all contents of $filename gets cleared` ... are  you saying the file is empty, or the lines that contain the string `Replace_ME` are removed (but the rest of the lines are still intact)?

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, `sed --version` doesn't display any output it returns `sed --help` for awk it displays `awk version 20200206`

Comment: @markp thanks for your reply, the whole file content gets cleared, no replacement done

Comment: @markp for my first code, if I remove `-i` it produces blank screen, but for this  code `sed -i "8i\Replace_ME=${Replaced}" "$filename` it produces desired output

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Android scripting env so fwiw ... any chance of upgrading your `sed` (and `awk`) software to newer (preferably GNU) versions?

Comment: Try it quotes with single quotes, just to be certain nothing is getting wildcard expanded. Clearly your output will then contain the literal text `${Replaced}`. You can build an argument by concatenating double-quoted sections and single-quoted sections if necessarily.

Comment: @ Gem thanks for your reply. Yes single quote works but as you said the variable does not expand

Comment: @mark Updating is however not an option as I'm trying to make a general purpose module for distribution

Comment: @mark thanks , I finally got it. `sed  -i -e 's/^MODDIR.*$/MODDIR='"${MODDIR}"'/' "$MODDIR/Detach"'`
The problem is the variable `MODDIR` wasn't double quoted `""`

Comment: The thing is I'm getting this `$MODDIR` from system output so it's not quoted while passing to `sed` any suggestions how can I make the content of `$MODDIR` inside double quote before passing to sed?

Comment: Say, `Another_Var=test/dir/test
MODDIR='"'${Another_Var}'"'`, when I `echo $MODDIR` then I get `"test/dir/test"` as output. But if I pass `$MODDIR` to sed then the content gets cleared again 

Comment: Okay I finally got the solution. It was happening because my variable had `/` so sed was failing. The solution is `sed  -i -e 's~^MODDIR.*$~MODDIR='"${MODDIR}"'~g' "$filename"`. Thanks everyone who tried to help me on this. Stack overflow is an amazing place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turned out the major issue was the variable content of `$Replaced` containing back slashs `/` eg, `Replaced=/test/dir/test` that's why sed was failing. To escape reserved character I needed to use `#`

```
sed  -i -e 's~^Replace_ME.*$~Replace_ME='"${Replaced}"'~g' "$filename"
```

So if you encounter a similar situation like me don't forget to use `~`

Resources: [How to pass a variable containing slashes to sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27787536/how-to-pass-a-variable-containing-slashes-to-sed)

Thanks everyone who invested their time to help me.