# How to use / in sed

Tags: shell, unix, sed

I have the below string in a file `filename="mongo-template.txt"`.

```
db.EndpointUrls.insert({"BACKEND_APP" : "DCC", "APPLICATION_NAME" : "dcc-core-api", "COUNTRY_CODE" : "IN", "ENDPOINT_URL" : "SERVICE-ENDPOINT");
```

I need to replace SERVICE-ENDPOINT with `https://test-in.mydomain.com/api/users`

```
filename="mongo-template.txt"

serviceendpoint="https://test-in.mydomain.com/api/users"
$sed "s/SERVICE-ENDPOINT/$serviceendpoint/g" "$filename"
```

I am getting the below error.

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 27: unknown option to `s'.
```

- If the serviceendpoint contains `/` character, I am getting the error.
- If the serviceendpoint does not contain `/` character, it replaces the string in the file.

The below link helped me to resolve my issue.

[How to pass a variable containing slashes to sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27787536/how-to-pass-a-variable-containing-slashes-to-sed)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16790793/how-to-insert-strings-containing-slashes-with-sed

Answer (score 0):

The standard solution is to use a different delimiter.  But you can also use perl:

```
$ repl=this/string/has/slashes
$ echo foo | sed "s|foo|$repl|g"
this/string/has/slashes
$ echo foo | r="$repl" perl -pe 's/foo/$ENV{r}/g'
this/string/has/slashes
$ echo foo | r="$repl" perl -MEnv -pE 's/foo/$r/g'
this/string/has/slashes
```