# Delete specific lines in range with sed

Tags: bash, sed

I am aware of several other questions related to this one such as: [Sed Unknown Option to s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366816/sed-unknown-option-to-s); however I am not having that problem. I am trying to run:

```
sed -n '/Ce./,/EOF/ {s!^#!! d} p' more_tests_high.job
```

but I keep getting:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 21: unknown option to `s'
```

I am trying to search `more_test_high.job` for text between `Ce` and `EOF`, but remove any comment lines which start with `#`. Yes, `EOF` is a literal text in the file that I want to search for. I have tried using `/` , `!`, and `_` as delimiters. I can run:

```
sed -n '/Ce./,/EOF/ p' more_tests_high.job
```

and see all the text that is between `Ce` and `EOF`, but how do I remove the commented lines that start with `#`?

Comment: You need a semicolon after the `!!` before the `d`.  And you need to think what you're doing; you edit the line and then delete it without printing what you just changed.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I added the semicolon after '!!' and then included the p inside the '}', but I don't get any output now.

Comment: You want `{/^#/d}`, I think. You don't need `s` to delete lines.

Comment: That did the trick if you want to submit an answer I'll accept it as correct. For the record the final total is `sed -n '/Ce./,/EOF/ {/^#/d;p}' more_tests_high.job`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command should look like this:

```
sed -n '/CE./,/EOF/{/^#/d;p}' more_tests_high.job
```

For all the lines between the `CE` and the `EOF` line, you check if they are a comment line, and if yes, you delete it, which restarts the cycle and ignores the `p`.

If it's not a comment line, it will be printed.

<sub>BSD sed (also found on Mac OS X) requires an extra semicolon between the `p` and the closing brace.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
 awk '/Ce./,/EOF/{if($0!~/^#/) print}' file
```

almost direct translation of the requirements without cryptic syntax.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/CE./,/EOF/!d;/^#/d' file
```

You are only interested in the range of lines between `CE.` and `EOF` therefore anything else delete. Once in the required range, delete any lines that begin `#`. Print all remaining lines.