# Script to Insert AWS API Credential

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to write a script to insert the API credentials in the awscreds.template. However, the Secret contains special characters.
As an example:

```
AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ5YhzvVUZnPTBVRA
AWSSecretKey=fRUZnUVUZnUvYhzvJVpwyn/xN3Oo0l3icqRy0//+
```

My script requests:

```
echo "Entre the Access Key, followed by an ENTER:"
read access
echo "Entre the Secret Key, followed by an ENTER:"
read secret
```

And then inserts it into the file:

```
sed -i '/AWSAccessKeyId=/s/$/'$access'/' awscreds.template

sed -i '/AWSSecretKey=/s/$/'$secret'/' awscreds.template
```

However, when I run the script I get the following:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 44: unknown option to `s'
```

After doing a bit of research, I made sure to use the *'* *'* to restrict the input, but I still get the same alarm. But why am I still getting this error?

Comment: Which version of `sed` are you using? i.e. output of `sed --version`. Working fine on `GNU sed version 4.2.1`

Comment: Good question. Pre-installed on the AMI: **GNU sed version 4.2.1**

Comment: What is the value of `secret` that did not work for you?

Comment: It's similar to the above with the '/' in the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the deliminator of *sed*. The credential contained */* which was also used in the *sed* statement. So I ended up just echoing the credentials into the file. I know it is not the most elegant way of doing this. But it worked well.

```
 echo "AWSAccessKeyId=$access" > awscreds.template
 echo "AWSSecretKey=$secret" >> awscreds.template
```

Answer (score 2):

The `AWSSecretKey` value contain `/` character which is used as a delimiter in your sed command.

Try to replace the sed subtitution delimiter with another character.

eg :

```
sed -i '/AWSAccessKeyId=/s~$~'"$access"'~' awscreds.template
sed -i '/AWSSecretKey=/s~$~'"$secret"'~' awscreds.template
```

Comment: Wow! Nice observation! Was thinking on similar-lines, just spot-on!

Comment: But if I replace it with another character, wouldn't that change the secret and as a result will not send metrics to AWS cloudwatch.

Comment: The secret will not be changed, you just replace sed `s` command delimiter here. See more about this issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366816/sed-unknown-option-to-s).

Comment: Replacing the delimiter just changes the problem from `/` to the replacement character, it doesn't solve it. Also there's other problematic characters likw `&` and `\1`. To solve it with sed you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed so you're better off just using awk since it can work with literal strings.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for the link but the AWS secret key is [40 alpha-numeric-slash-plus characters](https://alestic.com/2009/11/ec2-credentials/), so using `~` as delimiter is absolutely safe here. The missing part of the script might be a control to check for valid input.

Comment: @EdMorton I added the double quotes.

Comment: Yeah, I guess the missing part might be sanitizing the input but I find it unlikely that the person asking this question has thought of or knows how to do that. I would not assume that what the user enters is a valid AWS secret key.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use awk to do this robustly since sed cannot operate on arbitrary strings. This will work for any string in the input file or the replacement text:

```
$ secret='a&b/\t=\1' awk '/^AWSSecretKey=/ { sub(/=.*/,"="); $0=$0 ENVIRON["secret"] } 1' file
AWSSecretKey=a&b/\t=\1
```