# ndless-sdk build_toolchain.sh bash error

Tags: bash, gcc, sdk, cygwin

I'm trying to install Ndless-sdk on a windows machine. I spend a couple of time searching in several forums for a solution but cant find one..

Command: `bash ./build_toolchain.sh`

Output: (NO snippet: code formation did not work)

```
Building and installing to '/cygdrive/c/Users/Niklas/Desktop/Niklas/Spiele&Programme/Ndless/ndless-sdk/toolchain/install'...
Building Binutils...
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-cygwin
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-cygwin
checking target system type... arm-none-eabi
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether ln works... yes
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for gawk... gawk
checking to see if cat works as expected... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.exe
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... .exe
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc... yes
checking for gnatbind... no
checking for gnatmake... no
checking whether compiler driver understands Ada... no
checking how to compare bootstrapped objects... cmp --ignore-initial=16 $$f1 $$f2
checking for objdir... .libs
checking for isl 0.16, 0.15, or deprecated 0.14... no
recommended isl version is 0.16 or 0.15, the minimum required isl version 0.14 i
s deprecated
checking for isl 0.16 or 0.15... no
*** This configuration is not supported in the following subdirectories:
     zlib
    (Any other directories should still work fine.)
checking for default BUILD_CONFIG...
checking for --enable-vtable-verify... no
checking for bison... no
checking for byacc... no
checking for yacc... no
checking for bison... no
checking for gm4... no
checking for gnum4... no
checking for m4... no
checking for flex... no
checking for lex... no
checking for flex... no
checking for makeinfo... no
/cygdrive/c/Users/Niklas/Desktop/Niklas/Spiele&Programme/Ndless/ndless-sdk/toolc
hain/binutils-2.28/missing: line 81: makeinfo: command not found
checking for expect... no
checking for runtest... no
checking for ar... ar
checking for as... as
checking for dlltool... dlltool
checking for ld... (cached) /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_
64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld.exe
checking for lipo... no
checking for nm... nm
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for strip... strip
checking for windres... windres
checking for windmc... windmc
checking for objcopy... objcopy
checking for objdump... objdump
checking for readelf... readelf
checking for arm-none-eabi-cc... no
checking for arm-none-eabi-gcc... no
checking for arm-none-eabi-c++... no
checking for arm-none-eabi-g++... no
checking for arm-none-eabi-cxx... no
checking for arm-none-eabi-gxx... no
checking for arm-none-eabi-gcc... no
checking for arm-none-eabi-gcj... no
checking for arm-none-eabi-gfortran... no
checking for arm-none-eabi-gccgo... no
checking for arm-none-eabi-ar... no
checking for arm-none-eabi-as... no
checking for arm-none-eabi-dlltool... no
checking for arm-none-eabi-ld... no
checking for arm-none-eabi-lipo... no
checking for arm-none-eabi-nm... no
checking for arm-none-eabi-objcopy... no
checking for arm-none-eabi-objdump... no
checking for arm-none-eabi-ranlib... no
checking for arm-none-eabi-readelf... no
checking for arm-none-eabi-strip... no
checking for arm-none-eabi-windres... no
checking for arm-none-eabi-windmc... no
checking where to find the target ar... just compiled
checking where to find the target as... just compiled
checking where to find the target cc... pre-installed
checking where to find the target c++... pre-installed
checking where to find the target c++ for libstdc++... pre-installed
checking where to find the target dlltool... just compiled
checking where to find the target gcc... pre-installed
checking where to find the target gcj... pre-installed
checking where to find the target gfortran... pre-installed
checking where to find the target gccgo... pre-installed
checking where to find the target ld... just compiled
checking where to find the target lipo... pre-installed
checking where to find the target nm... just compiled
checking where to find the target objcopy... just compiled
checking where to find the target objdump... just compiled
checking where to find the target ranlib... just compiled
checking where to find the target readelf... just compiled
checking where to find the target strip... just compiled
checking where to find the target windres... just compiled
checking where to find the target windmc... just compiled
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
sed: -e expression #1, char 258: unknown option to `s'
make: *** No rule to make target 'all'.  Stop.
```

Is every `checking... no` an error where files are missing??
What does the least two lines mean?

> sed: -e expression #1, char 258: unknown option to `s'
>
> make: *** No rule to make target 'all'. Stop.

Comment: possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366816/sed-unknown-option-to-s  Try editing your config.status file and rework the sed expression to use something other than slash for separators

Comment: Thank you for editing my post and thanks for the tipp. The tip looks good but the config.status file get's reset every time i run the command..

Comment: Probably the `config` file is not supported on Cygwin, and/or you're trying to install to a weird directory. What parameters, if any, did you pass in? Can you link to the source of the package you are trying to install? The plethora of missing dependencies and other errors looks like you haven't installed things that are needed in order to finish compiling this.