# What's the meaning of this sed command?

Tags: regex, bash, sed, command

Can someone help me with this bash command please:

```
sed -i "s/\$CORPUS_DATA/$CORPUS_DATA/g" conf/*.xml
```

What does it mean?

Comment: tell us which part you understand and which ones you don't.. you can find some of the information in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sed/info

Comment: Well I know it is used to replace values but I have an error :

sed: -e expression #1, char 17: unknown option to `s'

Comment: in that case, please add an sample to show the failing case.. we cannot debug with command alone.. need sample input lines and sample values for variables used.. at a guess, the gotchas and links mentioned in these answer should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7680548 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366816/sed-unknown-option-to-s

Answer (score 2):

It replaces the value of the *text* "$CORPUS_DATA" in the file, to the actual value of the environment variable `$CORPUS_DATA`.

Test it:

```
$ CORPUS_DATA=hello
$ echo '$CORPUS_DATA'
$ $CORPUS_DATA
$ echo '$CORPUS_DATA' | sed "s/\$CORPUS_DATA/$CORPUS_DATA/g"
hello
```

Note that the first part escapes the `$` sign, so the regex will match the text "$CORPUS_DATA" literally. The second part doesn't, which means it takes the *value* of the env variable.

Comment: Well it's the second $ that is problematic. I have got this error : 

sed: -e expression #1, char 17: unknown option to `s'

Comment: @pokatore I can't reproduce.

Comment: The slash is only to escape the `$` _from the shell_.  A `$` at the very start of a regular expression is just fine. To escape it in the expression, you would have had to use `\\\$`.

Answer (score 1):

Following is the explanation of code.

```
sed -i "s/\$CORPUS_DATA/$CORPUS_DATA/g" conf/*.xml
```

`-i` is for saving the output into Input_file itself.

`s` using substitute option changing `\$CORPUS_DATA` with shell variable `$CORPUS_DATA` value.

`g` means do this change to all occurrences in current line.

`conf/*.xml` loop through all xml files in conf directory.