# replace variable using sed during string replacement

Tags: bash, sed

I have an xml file with a line: `<includes>xyz</includes>`

I have to append a value to xyz like `<includes>xyz abc/v1.2.3</includes>`

The value abc/v1.2.3 is stored in a variable: **stringReplace="abc/1.2.3"**

I am trying to achieve the same using sed:

```
sed -i -e "s/<includes>xyz<\/includes>/<includes>xyz\ $stringReplace<\/includes>/g" localConfig.xml
```

However, I am getting "sed: -e expression #1, char 41: unknown option to `s'".

Please help or any other way of doing it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sed fails with "unknown option to \`s'" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366816/sed-fails-with-unknown-option-to-s-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a slash / in the variable or file then use different separator (here i used | )

```
 sed -i -e "s|<includes>xyz</includes>|<includes>xyz $stringReplace</includes>|g" localConfig.xml
```