# Variable replacement in bash Scirpt

Tags: linux, bash

I have a script that runs through all the files in my local directory and finds key words in my terraform files. The issue I'm facing is that I'm unable to replace defined variables in the files. When I reference value to be replaced, it captures $variable as the reference instead. For example:

```
Repository_Name="test"

grep -rl '#{RepositoryName}#' --include *.tf |
  xargs gsed -i 's/#{RepositoryName}#/${Repository_Name}/g'
```

I've also tried removing the {} outside the variable like the example below and still no luck:

```
Repository_Name="test"

grep -rl '#{RepositoryName}#' --include *.tf |
  xargs gsed -i 's/#{RepositoryName}#/$Repository_Name/g'
```

The result I usually get is:

```
RepositoryName = "$Repository_Name"
```

or

```
RepositoryName = "${Repository_Name}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `"` for the variables to be evaluated

```
Repository_Name="test"

grep -rl '#{RepositoryName}#' --include *.tf | xargs gsed -i "s/#{RepositoryName}#/${Repository_Name}/g"
```

You may also need extra `{` if you want them in the file.

Comment: Would I need to include the -e flag ?

Comment: To `gsed`? It's not  required

Comment: I'm getting this error: gsed: -e expression #1, char 58: unknown option to `s'

Comment: There are no 58 chars in your example, so you are running something different

Comment: this worked. - https://stackoverflow.com/a/9366940/14329701 - I think the issue here was the character i had in the tf files creating char issues with sed.

Answer (score 0):

Actually sed is enough:

```
sed -i '/#{RepositoryName}#/'"s||$Repository_Name|g" *.tf
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this issue

```
grep -rl '#{RepositoryName}#' --include *.tf |
  xargs gsed -i "s@#{RepositoryName}#@${Repository_Name}@g"
```

There were char complications with sed.

[for reference](/a/9366940/14329701)