# sed is not working when I use variables

Tags: bash, sed

This works if I don't use variables. I don't understand why it won't work when I place variables inside. Can anyone help? The variables contain a path to a file.

```
sed s/$old/$new/ Current_series_list.txt"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [About replacing string with sed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976975/about-replacing-string-with-sed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paths may contain forward slashes. Use a different character for separating the command arguments, such as `#`:

```
sed "s#$old#$new#" Current_series_list.txt
```

Of course, this is still fragile due to regex metacharacters. Consider using the following instead:

```
ruby -e '$stdin.each_line { |l| puts l.sub(ARGV[0], ARGV[1]) }' \
     "$old" "$new" < Current_series_list.txt
```

A more portable equivalent in Perl is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thanks, can I send the result bach to the same file with <Current_series_list.txt?

Comment: Use `sed -i` for in-place editing. No, you cannot use redirection (easily) to read and write a file at the same time; and certainly, input redirection is not the right tool here.

Comment: @user2764736 [sponge(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sponge) should be useful here. Append `| sponge Current_series_list.txt` to the command.

Comment: perl -e '($o,$n)=@ARGV;while(<STDIN>){s/$o/$n/;print}' "$old" "$new" < Current_series_list.txt

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of `old` and `new`? If they contain slashes, then they will expand the sed pattern to something that isn't valid. Your trailing quotation mark probably is also not helping.